# Use a triple integral to find the volume of a tetrahedron

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Problem: Use a triple integral to find the volume of the tetrahedron bounded by the planes $x+y+z=1$, $x=y$, $x=0$, $z=0$.

I drew (what I believe to be) the solid bounded by the regions. However, I am having difficulty finding the bounds for the triple integral. I think they are:

- $1-z-x ≤ y ≤ x $
- $0 ≤ x ≤ y$
- $0 ≤ z ≤ 1$

But, I am not sure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I would first make a sketch of the solid boundry. By getting three points from the relation x+y+z=1 by plugging in 0 for two of the variables and solving for the other. You get the points (1,0,0), (0,0,1),(0,1,0). I would sketch that first, then put the plane equation in terms of two variables, I.e. z=1-x-y. Thus you can see that z goes from 0 to 1-x-y. In addition the bounds for x and y are determined by its projection in the xy plane, a triangle, with the hypotenuse y=1-x.

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake I didn't see the x=y part.  Scratch what I said these are the bounds: z goes from 0 to z=1-x-y, x goes from x=y to x=1-y, and y goes from 0 to 1/2. If you cut sections over x, meaning make x your outer integral you have to use two double integrals for the xy region or in other words two triple integrals, not fun. Y=1/2 should be the intersection of the lines, not y=1. X=y, x=1-y, y=1-y, y=1/2. Meaning (1,1,0), should be (1/2,1/2,0).

Comment: I see, so the point that I have labeled (1,1,0) is actually (.5,.5,0)? Could I use a triple integral where you first integrate over z, then x, then y? Thank you again! @user163751

Comment: Yeah. That's the one I described. (0<=y <=1/2), (y <=x<=1-y), (0 <=z <=1-x-y). Dzdxdy

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help!